what the electronic board is this
I have a few questions:
First
Does anyone know what the electronic board is this....
Or what electronic board this homemade electronic board is based on?



What is the circuit meant to do?

@Andrew
It's part of a car alarm homemade system . FL817 burst in the winter in freezing temperatures up to -40°C ... Somehow this homemade board reads some component via USB connection Depending on whether it is read or unread, the car will either start or not. And it's a problem that's been bothering me I bought the fl817 - as soon as I have some free time, I'll do it again. I'll take this unit out from under the dashboard, disassemble it. solder out the fl817 and replace it with a new one. I will also take a photo of it and I will contact this forum again for explanations.

@SergeyE please do not put information into a comment ... edit the question instead

Just some bog standard proto board with components soldered on. It's not a specific commercial/off-the-shelf PCB or development kit.
No idea what it does - it appears to be some sort of 555 timer circuit. The 555 timer is a TI NE555P, while the chips on the right appear to be Fairchild FOD817 optocouplers (based on the Fairchild logo and the number 817). You'd have to remove it from the case and trace the connections to find out the circuit.

yes , i'd have to remove it from the case and trace the connections to find out the circuit.

The circuit board looks like one of these:
https://www.amazon.com/Eagles-2x8-Prototype-Protoboard-Compatible/dp/B09LYW7VZZ/?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_w=hrpXC&content-id=amzn1.sym.976dd35f-578a-4e78-adcf-960f58b6202f%3Aamzn1.symc.f3a6ae52-fb92-4bbd-ba18-628777ebc1c0&pf_rd_p=976dd35f-578a-4e78-adcf-960f58b6202f&pf_rd_r=YXEZWXWAF34T57Q1SY3X&pd_rd_wg=WlZVl&pd_rd_r=fa8f3862-b1af-4f2f-8a19-f571f6d0314e&ref_=pd_hp_d_atf_ci_mcx_mr_ca_hp_atf_d&th=1
You can see the letters across the top, and it appears to be only 6 holes tall.
Search for "protoboard printed circuit board" and you'll find dozens of similar boards.
